# How can I keep a mat-tab active when I navigate to a subchild of its route in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular-router, mat-tab

I am using `mat-tab-nav-bar` to show 2 tabs as listed below:

**tabs.component.html**:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a
    mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index"
    [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
    routerLinkActive
    #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive"
    (click)="activeLinkIndex = i"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
  >
    {{ routeLink.label | translate }}
  </a>
</nav>
```

**tabs.component.ts**:

```
routeLinks = [
      {
        label: 'Overview',
        link: '/tabs/overview',
        index: 0
      },
      {
        label: 'Products',
        link: '/tabs/products',
        index: 1
      },
    ];
```

**app.routing.module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'overview',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/overview/overview.module').then(m => m.OverviewModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'products',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/products/products.module').then(m => m.ProductsModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'products/:productID',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/products/product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule)
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/overview',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

When I am navigating to /products, the tab is active. But when I am navigating to /products/:productID, the tab is not active. How can I keep it active since it is in the /products route?

I also tried to make the /products/:productID child of /products route but it does not work. Updated here in my **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'overview',
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/overview/overview.module').then(m => m.OverviewModule)
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'products',
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/products/products.module').then(m => m.ProductsModule)
              },
              {
                path: ':productID',
                loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/product/product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule)
              }
            ]
          }
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/overview',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Comment: It is not active because with your configuration, `products` and `products/:productId` are 2 unrelated routes and the router only checks if the currently active route matches `products`.It probably makes more sense to make `products/:productId` a child of `products`.

Comment: To clarify, if you were to make `products/:productId` a child of `products` you won't need the `products` part of the child since it's already in the parent route.

Comment: @MikeS. I tried what you suggested and it does not work also. see my code below.

Comment: Why are you setting `routerLinkActiveOptions` to `exact: true`?

Comment: @PoulKruijt thank you so much!!! that was the problem!

Comment: @KathrineHanson You're welcome :) ill post it as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have child routes also activate your `routerLinkActive`, you need to set:

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }"
```